# Selected Hover no background

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div wit an unordered list.

If i click on a item i add the class selected.

so the selected item always is like

```
   <li class="selected">
```

For all the li item i use.

```
   li:hover
{
    background-color:#CECEC8;
}
```

This works.

and for selected items i use

```
.selected
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;   
}
.selected :hover
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;
}
```

But when i click the selected item and the mouse is still on it (so its hovering over it) the color dosnt change but is still #CECEC8 from li:hover instead of #8B8BFF from.selected :hover.

**How can i overrule the li:hover when clicked so the background color of a list item with class=selected is always #8B8BFF even on hover.**

The problem is now it isnt immediately visible if you clicked, the color dosnt change from normal hover.

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/FCGtc/1/

Comment: yes this is normal i've checked it and it's happen because you targeting direct tag and if you can understand first tag css works after this id and class css will work so you have to change some of your code

Comment: Try `:active` for clicking states

Comment: i mean after the clicked so it is clicked (its not active then )

Comment: Note that you have an extra gap here: `.selected :hover`

Comment: Note that `li.selected` will have higher specificity than `li:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: As the solution differs to the problem in your fiddle, I'll give you two solutions, one for the code in the question and one for your Fiddle**

**Code in question:**

There's a space between your `:hover` declaration, remove that. Also, it's about **specificity**. `li:hover` is **more specific** than `.selected:hover` because of the `li`.

Use the following to keep the same level of specificity:

```
li:hover
{
    background-color:#CECEC8;
}

li.selected
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;   
}

li.selected:hover
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FCGtc/8/

**Code in Fiddle:**

It's because your initial hover selector is a **more specific match** than your class selector (also remove the space between `:hover`).

Use these, no need for that **god awful** `important`:

```
#browsecat li.selectedcat
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;   
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FCGtc/9/

Comment: Why did you add an ID selector?

Comment: @MMM Because the `#browsecat li:hover` (he's using for his normal hover) is **more specific** than `li.selectedcat:hover`. Try changing it in my fiddle, it will no longer work.

Comment: @MMM He **doesn't want** `.selectedcat` to change to the colours that `#browsecat li:hover` specifies. Because that hover uses an ID selector, we **must be equally as specific** in order to override it, therefore we need an ID selector.

Comment: I get that, stop **bolding your words**, he clearly says "background color of a list item with class=selected is always #8B8BFF even on hover"

Comment: @MMM I'm trying to emphasise the words for you. He wants to override his existing `hover` rule.

Comment: You're emphasising truisms, all I'm saying that the answer to his question (not his fiddle) does not require ID selectors.

Comment: @MMM Well it boils down to what does he want, an answer to his code provided, or an answer to his Fiddle? We have both provided one to each. I guess the OP needs to decide on which fits his actual code (and not the example code).

Comment: Why is !important a bad thing?

Comment: No, it always boils down to answering the actual question, so that other people looking for answers to their problems can find them easily, **unless** the actual question is entailed in a fiddle. If someone looks at the question, then an answer with ID selectors and thinks they are necessary for some reason, that will be confusing.

Comment: `!important` overrides specificity and makes it more difficult to manage your CSS. You should only use it if you have to (you don't in this case).

Comment: @MMM The thing is, his problem is actually different to what the question asks (which is sometimes the case here). The real problem he is having is precedence of CSS rule specificity.

Comment: You still need to fix your solutions: Your first solution's third statement is unnecessary and your second solution uses the same colour twice (so related to the first solution).

Comment: @MMM Whilst you're correct about the second solution, you are incorrect about the first. Try deleting that third statement in my Fiddle, you'll see selected items still turn grey on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this behaviour because `ID` always have a **higher specificity** tan `class`. In your fiddle, if I change all `id` to `class`, it works as you expected.

If you like Star Wars, you could retrieve more info about css specificity [here](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).

Or, if not, this is [a serious one](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/css_specificity.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use :

```
#browsecat li:hover
{
    background-color:#CECEC8;
}
#browsecat li.selectedcat
{
    background-color:#8B8BFF;   
}
```

No need to use `!important`.

http://jsfiddle.net/8vYqM/

PS : You should learn about css specificity : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0):

to override :hover you need to be more specific, and use :hover

```
li.selected:hover {
  background-color:#8B8BFF;
}
```